# Mybatis/Oracle out parameter: Result Maps collection does not contain value for "TestEntity"

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, mybatis

I used the out parameter of Oracle procedure. The out parameter returns one object only, which has a nested object of Oracle type. The out paraemter should be an exactly mapping of the java bean TestEntity but mybatis said the result didn't contain the TestEntity

Please help

Java Beans:

```
@Data
public class BaseEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

And

```
@Data
public class TestEntity {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private BaseEntity client;
}
```

Java Mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface TestMapper {
    List<TestEntity> getAll(@Param("outParam") TestEntity outParam);
}
```

XML mapper:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="org.ssc.gss.mapper.TestMapper" >

    <resultMap id="TestEntity" type="org.ssc.gss.entity.TestEntity">
        <result property="name" column="NAME" />
        <result property="description" column="DESCRIPTION" />
        <result property="client" column="CLIENT" typeHandler="org.ssc.gss.utils.OracleBaseEntityHandler" />
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getAll"  statementType="CALLABLE"  >
        call TEST_GET_BASEDETAILS(#{c1, mode=OUT, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet,  resultMap="TestEntity"})
    </select>
</mapper>
```

DB Objects:

```
 CREATE TABLE CLIENTS (
      ID NUMBER ,
      NAME VARCHAR2(40) unique,
      DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(200),
          CONSTRAINT CLIENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID) USING INDEX  ENABLE
      )
  /
 CREATE TABLE DELIVERABLES (
                                ID NUMBER ,
                                NAME varchar2(30),
                                CLIENTID NUMBER,
                                DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(200)
  )
  /


 CREATE TYPE BASEENTITYTYPE IS OBJECT
  (
  ID NUMBER,
  NAME VARCHAR2(30),
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(200)
  );
  /

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_base_details(
    i_p_id IN number,
    i_p_type IN VARCHAR2
  ) return BASEENTITYTYPE
  IS
   o_detail BASEENTITYTYPE;
  BEGIN
   o_detail :=  BASEENTITYTYPE(i_p_id, null, null);
  BEGIN
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(i_p_type) = 'CLIENT'
      THEN
  SELECT NAME, DESCRIPTION INTO o_detail.NAME, o_detail.DESCRIPTION FROM CLIENTS where ID = o_detail.id;
  END case;
  END;
  return o_detail;
  END;
  /


 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_GET_BASEDETAILS(c1 out sys_refcursor)
  AS
  BEGIN
    OPEN c1 for
   SELECT d.name, d.DESCRIPTION, get_base_details(d.clientID,'CLIENT')  client  FROM deliverables d;
  END;
  /

 INSERT INTO CLIENTS(ID, NAME, description) values (1, 'A','AAA');
 INSERT INTO CLIENTS(ID, NAME, description) values (2, 'B','bbb');
 Insert into deliverables values(1,'D1',1, 'CCC');
```

Test in SQLPlus:

```
SQL> var cur refcursor
SQL> exec TEST_GET_BASEDETAILS(:cur)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print cur

NAME|DESCRIPTION|CLIENT(ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION)
D1|CCC|BASEENTITYTYPE(1, 'A', 'AAA')
```

Test in Springboot:

```
    @Test
    void getAll() {
        TestEntity d = new TestEntity();
        try {
            testMapper.getAll(d);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.info(e.getClass().getName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
    }
```

Error message:

org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

#### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection does not contain value for "TestEntity"

#### Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection does not contain value for "TestEntity"

```
at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:96)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:441)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.selectList(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try removing the double quotes in the parameter reference i.e. `resultMap="TestEntity"` -> `resultMap=TestEntity`.

Comment: Thanks ave! You are always so insightful! I'm so impressed when I looked around your posts - you are a piece of gem for stackoverflow- I'm sure you are playing other roles well in other platform but this is the only place I know you

Comment: You're very welcome! As a member of the MyBatis team, I'm trying to be helpful. =D

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @ave, who is a master of mybatis...
So - Java beans, xml mapper, java mapper etc => see above
a correction need to be made as @ave pointed out:
From:

```
        call TEST_GET_BASEDETAILS(#{c1, mode=OUT, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet,  resultMap="TestEntity"})
```

to:

```
        call TEST_GET_BASEDETAILS(#{c1, mode=OUT, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet,  resultMap=TestEntity})
```

And other considerations:

1. My assumption is the DB would return only one row(due to the other constraints made) but to make it more generic & the resultset would treat the one record return as the first object in the array, I changed my out parameter from one object(d) to a mapper
   From

```
@Test
    void getAll() {
        TestEntity d = new TestEntity();
        try {
            testMapper.getAll(d);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.info(e.getClass().getName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
    }
```

to:

```
@Test
    void getAll() {
         Map<String, ?> outParam = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            testMapper.getAll(outParam );
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.info(e.getClass().getName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
    }
```

2. The mapper.xml need to be updated

from

```
#{c1
```

to

```
#{outParam.c1, mode=OUT, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet,  resultMap=TestEntity})
```

the outParms can include multiple out parameters and each is mapped to the cursor's name

3. The type handler java class

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.ssc.gss.entity.BaseEntity;
import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;

public class OracleBaseEntityHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<BaseEntity> {
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());


    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i,
                                    BaseEntity parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        OracleConnection oconn =(OracleConnection) ps.getConnection();

        Object[] o = new Object[3]; // this "3" is because the BaseEntity java bean has 3 fields
        o[0] = parameter.getId();
        o[1] = parameter.getName();
        o[2] = parameter.getDescription();
        Struct struct = oconn.createStruct("BASEENTITYTYPE",o);
        ps.setObject(i, struct);

    }


    @Override
    public BaseEntity getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
          Struct struct =(java.sql.Struct) rs.getObject(columnName);
          return extractObject(struct);
    }

    @Override
    public BaseEntity getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {

        Struct struct =(java.sql.Struct) rs.getObject(columnIndex);

        return extractObject(struct);
    }

    @Override
    public BaseEntity getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {

        Struct struct =(java.sql.Struct) cs.getObject(columnIndex);

        return extractObject(struct);
    }

    protected BaseEntity extractObject(Struct o) throws SQLException {
        if (o == null) {
            return null;
        }
        BaseEntity b = new BaseEntity();
        Object[] attrs = o.getAttributes();
        b.setId(Long.parseLong(attrs[0].toString()));
        b.setName(attrs[1].toString());
        b.setDescription(attrs[2].toString());
        return b;
    }
}
```

My code is not smart :) but it achieves what I want to do.
For much better code, see this one(I believe it's owned by ave): https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-56834806